# Own method displayed in django template

Tags: python, django, methods, django-templates

I wrote my / sample method and want to show it in the django template.
I am trying to `{{filter.my_method}}` and nothing it does not give.
Below my model with the method and view.

My model and my method:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

    def my_method(self):
        return self.name
```

My view

```
class Index(ListView):

    template_name = "index.html"
    context_object_name = 'users'

    def get(self, request):
        filter = Filter(request.GET, queryset=MyModel.objects.all())
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'filter': filter})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call this method not on the filter but on the model instance:

```
{% for obj in filter %}
    {{ obj.my_method }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Filter.objects.all() returns a list when evaluated while your method is running on single instances. This answer will let you run your method on every instance in that queryset.

Comment: @cdvv7788 and catavaran - Thanks :)